# Problems for which there is no algorithm with smallest time complexity

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Are there any problems where there is no smallest time complexity, so there is a big-$\mathcal{O}$ but no big-$\Theta$?

More formally, I am looking for any problem $p$ where

- for any algorithm that solves $p$ in time $f(n)$
- there provably exists another algorithm that solves $p$ in time $g(n)$
- where $g(n) = o(f(n))$.

An example would be a problem for which there exist algorithms of complexity $\mathcal{O}(n^k)$ for all $k > 0$, but for which there is no algorithm of lower complexity, like $\mathcal{O}(1)$ or $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$.

Comment: There is no $<$ relation between $O(f)$ and $O(g)$, you could use the little $o$ notation and say $g(n)=o(f(n))$. One example for what you required in your last statement could be finding an element in a sorted array. I think [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/310/decision-problem-such-that-any-algorithm-admits-an-exponentially-faster-algorith) post answers the question in the title.

Comment: @Ariel Thanks, I've never heard of Blum's  Speedup Theorem before. I fixed the niggles in the post as well.

Answer (score 3):

The existence of such problems follows from the [Blum speedup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%27s_speedup_theorem). The theorem shows, for example, that there exists a problem such that for any algorithm solving it in time $T(n)$, there is another one solving it in time at most $\log T(n)$.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any good examples? I don't have time to read the proof right now.

Comment: Not really. The examples constructed by the theorem are very contrived.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in something similar to what you are describing (in terms of a hierarchy of algorithms of different runtimes that get closer and closer to some limiting runtime). *Polynomial time approximation schemes* (PTAS) have runtimes stated like $O(2^{1/\epsilon}n^2)$ or $O(n^{1/\epsilon})$ for any epsilon, and you are sort of free to pick your epsilon as a trade-off between the runtime or the accuracy to an approximate solution.

See http://www.win.tue.nl/~mdberg/Onderwijs/AdvAlg_Material/Course%20Notes/lecture7.pdf for an intro to PTAS and an example showing a $O(n^3/\epsilon)$ PTAS for a solution to Knapsack which is at least $(1-\epsilon)\times OPT$